# Präsentation machen/zeigen/durchführen or Folien zeigen?

Tags: word-choice

How can I say I want to show a PowerPoint presentation for about 15 minutes? (So that someone can book me a time slot).

1. Ich will eine kurze, 10-15-minutige Präsentation machen.
2. Ich will eine kurze, 10-15-minutige Präsentation zeigen.
3. Ich will paar Folien zeigen und brauche dafür 10 bis 15 Minuten.

Which sentence is correct and understandable? Or shall I use a different wording.

Answer (score 4):

All of these are correct (with very minor issues, see below) and understandable, it's really just a matter of taste.

(3) is missing an article, it should be:

> 3. Ich will ein paar Folien zeigen und brauche dafür 10 bis 15 Minuten.

For me, they are becoming better from (1) to (3), with (3) being the best.

Another good alternative for the verb would be *halten*:

> Ich will eine kurze, 10-15-minütige Präsentation halten.

EDIT:
Sorry, I didn't catch this first: it is *min**ü**tige*, not *min**u**tige*.

Comment: Indeed "halten" sounds much better for me. And thank you for the hint regarding the missing umlaut in "minütige" and the missing article - in my native language we don't have any of those.